# How to customize date in Magento admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

In my project I need to have only "day" and "month" to select no "year" or "h:m:s" required so I would like to set format to "d M" to bemore precise day (number) and month name as it is in "LONG" date format.
I already tried:

```
        $fieldset->addField('date_to', 'date', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('dingles')->__('Date to'),
            'name'      => 'date_to',
            'time'      => false,
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'    => 'd M'
        ));
```

but it won't work, also it gives me hour:minute:second anyway.
Is it possible to format it as I wanted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to display column in grid?
If yes, then change type from date to datetime as shown below:

```
$this->addColumn(
 Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->formatUrlKey($key),
  array(
   'header'   => Mage::helper('core')->__($label),
   'index'    => $key,
   'filter'   => $isFilterable,
   'sortable' => true,
   'type' => 'datetime',
   'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'dateFilter'),
   )
 );
```

Comment: Hi not necesserily should be fine if i can select day and month only while editing/adding new event however then while event is executed filter should be able to select correcy event

Comment: what is $isFilterable variable?